# Cannot find an overload for 'contains' that accepts an argument list of type in Swift

Tags: swift, contains

I want to check the similar object from my custom array in swift.
I am using contains method but i am getting an error.

```
var companies:[Company] = [Company]()
var company = Company()

if !contains(self.companies,company) //I am having an error here
{
    ...
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find an overload for 'contains' that accepts an argument list of type '([Company], Company)'
```

Comment: See the update to the accepted answer (i.e. use `self.companies.contains(company)`).

Comment: dasblinkenlight,  self.companies.contains(company) is says me that  [Company] is not have member name contains. Please suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as a workaround - cast to NSArray

```
(companies as NSArray).containsObject(company)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just need `Company` to be `Equatable`. Something like this:

```
struct Company: Equatable {

}

func ==(lhs: Company, rhs: Company) -> Bool {
    return true // Do your custom implementation that returns true if lhs and hrs should be considered equal
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Matteo Piombo, How do i pass it my array to the function? Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: You do not have to. `Company` should conform to `Equatable` since `contains` uses `==` in order to decide if two `Company` have to be considered equal. The error you see might be due to the fact that your `Company` type is not equatable, thus there is no explicit way to decide if two different instances have to be considered equal.

Comment: great...its not giving me a compilation error now..ll run the code and let you know